# Serial Port Async Read

Tags: python, asynchronous, serial-port

I've a python script and setup a serial port where I want to read data from some sensors. Since I don't know when the data is available is it possible to get an event when data is available? Or any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

[Futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html) might be useful. You can create a `Future` object which you would `set_result()` to once the data becomes available.

In the meantime, you can check if the future is `done()` to see if a value is present.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example? What about async and await? Did this not work?